# Superscript and Subscript in Android App XML

Tags: android, xml, subscript, superscript

I am parsing data from an XML file which has subscript and superscript characters in them which I got from the character map. Like so:

```
<value column="Back" null="false">H₂</value>
```

but when I display it on a textview in Android it gives me this 'Hâ,,'

How can I fix this and display it properly in my app?

Comment: I doubt this will work, but try <value column="Back" null="false"><text>H<subscript>2</subscript></text></value> and/or <value column="Back" null="false">H<subscript>2</subscript></value>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out how

In the XML file the code should be like this :

`<value column="Back" null="false">H&lt;sub&gt;2&lt;/sub&gt;</value>`

So that the parced string value is `"H<sub>2</sub>"`
then in the java code :

```
TextView textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(YourString);
```

and for superscript use "sup" instead of "sub"

Answer (score 5):

You can use `<small>` tag along with `<sub>` or `<sup>` tags to decrease the size of the text.

For example:`<sup><small>your-string</small></sup>`

If you want to still decrease the size of text,you add `<small>` tag once more like this`<sup><small><small>your-string</small></small></sup>`

I'm using android studio and it is working perfectly for me !

Answer (score 5):

i found this method useful for me.

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="your_string">H<sub>2</sub></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it easier than that, just write in @strings or where you want`<sub>your-string-here</sub>` for subscript or `<sup>your-string-here</sup>`. 
The subscripted letters(of your word) still have the same size as your text. You need to decrease it's size. 
For that, use , where number means the size of the text you want.