# Subscript 5 in Android strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, unicode

Subscript 2 is displayed correctly in all the following cases:

- Directly pasting the utf-8 character

  > `<string name="subscript_two">₂</string>`
- Using the hex escape

  > `<string name="subscript_two">&#x2082;</string>`
- Using the decimal escape

  > `<string name="subscript_two">&#8322;</string>`

But all the following cases display subscript 5 as regular 5.

- Directly pasting the utf-8 character

  > `<string name="subscript_five">₅</string>`
- Using the hex escape

  > `<string name="subscript_five">&#x2085;</string>`
- Using the decimal escape

  > `<string name="subscript_five">&#8325;</string>`

What's up with that?

It is rendered correctly in Android Studio's Layout Preview (on API 23), but not on my testing device that runs on CM 11, which is a fork of Kitkat 4.4.4 .

Now I know the `Html.fromHtml()` hack answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15849718/1944049), but I expect there's a cleaner way to make it happen in strings.xml itself - since subscript 2 works just fine.

I need it for putting P₂O₅ in EditText's hint and TextView, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscript 1 to 4 are inbuilt. They will always work. 
But to use subscript 5 to 9 you need to use html code inside your string
    `<sub><small>5</small></sub>` to get <sub>5</sub>

Same applies for superscript 
    `<sup><small>5</small></sup>` to get this <sup>5</sup>

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that only 1 to 4 are supported. I tried `<string name="subscript_5"><sub><small>5</small></sub></string>` but it doesn't work. I think it'll work if I set it in Java. I was hoping to do it in strings.xml itself. Anyway, thanks a bunch. :) Accepting your answer for the time being. Hope they add support for more unicodes in future.